# How would I call a helper from a helper in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm writing some custom helpers in Codeigniter and I want to call some functions from other helper files like date, etc, in my helper. I keep getting "call to undefined function" errors. How can I reference other helper functions from my helper?

Thx

D

Comment: I'm starting to lean away from CI because of things like this. Also, what if one model contains another model? Or if a controller extends another controller? It looks like Kohana solves these issues, I can't wait to give it a try on my next project...

Comment: @Kevin. What issues do you have about controllers extending controllers and accessing models from another model?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As you can see from the source link provided, calling `$this` in reference to the CodeIgniter object is only available within your controllers, models and views. 
However to take full use of CodeIgniter's native resources from outside those, you simply have to make an instance of it like this:

```
$instanceName =& get_instance();
```

Then, to access those resources, instead of using `$this->`, you'd be using `$instanceName->`.

[Source](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html)

Comment: It was my first answer here, I was a bit scared, glad you got it right:P

Answer (score 19):

```
function first_function()
{
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $ci->load->helper('date');
    $mysql = '20061124092345';
    $unix = mysql_to_unix($mysql);
}
```